# File not found. Trying to execute a script but file not found?

Tags: unix

I am not able to execute a script i am trying to develop.  It is in my directory but i get the following.

```
.*../nfloyd<181> ls recrea*
+ ls recreateview.sh
recreateview.sh
.../nfloyd<182> ./recreateview.sh
+ ./recreateview.sh
ksh: ./recreateview.sh: not found [No such file or directory]
.../nfloyd<183>*
```

Comment: Does the file have execute privileges? Try `chmod +x <filename>`.

Comment: please post your efforts along with issue you are facing. How would people come to know what's the problem without knowing it :)

Comment: Does the filename have any invisible characters? Try `ls recrea* | od -c` or `./recre*`.

Comment: here are the results from ls recrea* | od -c .../nfloyd<187> ls recrea* | od -c
+ od -c
+ ls recreateview.sh
0000000   r   e   c   r   e   a   t   e   v   i   e   w   .   s   h  \n
0000020
i don't understand the \n at the end.  Also i did make sure the permissions were 777  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the first two bytes of your script are `#!` and are followed by a non-existent program path. If your script doesn't require a non-standard command interpreter, you can just drop the line.